# Javascript Inserting a clone ordering issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clone and insert items in order in JS, I can clone and add elements but the order seems to be incorrect, I am trying to assign a value to the radio buttons so I can tie the radio buttons to the text fields as seen below:

```
<div id='1'>
            <div class="template">
                <div>
                    <label class="right inline">Response:</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" name="responseText[]" value="" maxlength="400" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="responsCheck[]" value="0" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" name="addNewRow" value="Add Row" />
            </div>
        </div>
JS:

var $counter = 0;
var $template = $('.template');
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    var $elem = $template.clone();
    $elem.find("input:text").val("");
    $copy.find("input:radio").val($counter);
    $elem.insertAfter($template);
});
```

If I add three rows for example, the Values of the checkbuttons are in the following order:

```
0
2
1
```

I need the Values to be in the following order:

```
0
1
2
```

anybody got any ideas? I think it must be the way I am inserting the clone? When I am using radio buttons this line seems to work:
$elem.insertAfter($('#1 .clone').last());

but when using checkboxes it doesn't seem to work any ideas?

Comment: Well why aren't you doing the insertion the same way?

Comment: I am - I copied and pasted my form and simply changed the radio button for checkboxes no luck - I can still insert a row just not in order

Comment: No, you said you did `$elem.insertAfter($('#1 .clone').last())`, but the code you posted for the checkboxes does not do that.

Answer (score 2):

To me problem looks like that on adding second entry $template still points to the first entry.

I would try by moving $template initialization inside click handler and changing it like below.

```
var $counter = 0;
$('input[type=button]').click(function() {
    var $template = $('.template:last');
});
```

This way $template should point to the last template inserted and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use:

```
$("#1").append($elem);
```

instead

```
$elem.insertAfter($template);
```

Or select the last every time.

```
var $template = $('.template').last();
```

Comment: I'll give it a go and select your answer as right if works thanks

Comment: Check ashutosh answer, that works, the first way will insert the element after the button, and the second does't work cause you are selecting the element only one time.

Answer (score 0):

Put them into a js array and sort them by val:

```
function SortByValue(elem1, elem2){
   var e1 = Number($(elem1).val());
   var e2 = Number($(elem2).val()); 
   return ((e1 < e2) ? -1 : ((e1 > e2) ? 1 : 0));
}

var sortedValues = $.makeArray($(jQSelector)).sort(SortByValue);
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JWells/ksC93/)

Comment: Will this really work? I don't think sorting like this will reflect the changes in DOM.

Comment: Yes - it will work. I edited the answer and provided a fiddle. ;)

Comment: There are many things wrong with that approach even though functionally correct. I would never recommend sorting elements when they can just be appended. You are making something Order (1) to nlogn. Also you are manually applying changes to DOM by updating innerHTML. The snipped you posted in your answer just sorts which is incomplete and as I said will not update DOM.

Comment: Inserting elements into the DOM is also manipulating the DOM, which is the premise of the question. That said - the fiddle demonstrates the `SortByValue` approach works and is, as you say, functionally correct. There's no single correct answer to the question and my answer might be helpful to others with similar questions but different circumstances.